# Spring Social + build in SignUp and Login

Tags: spring-security, facebook-login, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I need to integrate Spring Social in an app and make it work with normal signin and login that use spring security. I've manage to make them work separately, but having trouble to make them work together. To implement only Spring Social Facebook I followed [**this**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/) tutorial and with a little tweaking (cause its outdated and .getUserProfile() doesn't work) I've managed to authenticate user and retrieve all data I need. On the other side I have my app that using spring security to signup and login. Below is config file for my app.
What i've tried to do is to implement everything from  [**spring social facebook tutorial**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/) to my app. But its seems not working.

The question is how to implement them together? so user have a choice to register via app or facebook.

**WebSecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  DetailService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler())
        .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
  }

  public AuthenticationSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler() {
    return (request, response, authentication) -> response.sendRedirect("/");
  }

  public AuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler() {
    return (request, response, exception) -> {
      response.sendRedirect("/login");
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension() {
    return new EvaluationContextExtensionSupport() {
      @Override
      public String getExtensionId() {
        return "security";
      }

      @Override
      public Object getRootObject() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {
        };
      }
    };
  }

}
```